# how to get the base url

Tags: php, url

i created a simple spaghetti code, wherein a user inputs data, then shall receive an email..my question is, how to include the url of the portal without having to hardcode it such as

```
http://www.test.com/index.php?activate=$test
```

that is, http://www.test.com <-- this is all i want

is there a built-in function that i can use in order to be able to use the url of the portal and send the correct path to the recipient ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php) global variable and its keys.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
        echo 'https://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    } else {
        echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    }
?>
```

> `$_SERVER` is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here. That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the *CGI/1.1* specification, so you should be able to expect those.

Answer (score 2):

The base url is stored in the superglobal array `$_SERVER` (More info: [PHP.Net: $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)). You can also use a `phpinfo()` to see what variables are available with their values.

Answer (score 0):

try this

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']